Elasticsearch trust establishment between 2 clusters using Self-signed certificates
I am trying to setup a CCR (cross cluster replication) between two of my Elasticsearch clusters (one in singapore region and another in mumbai region). Now I am facing an issue in connecting the two clusters since I have used self signed certificates and not ca certificates for creating these clusters (since this is just for testing purpose, and I don't have a domain to generate ca certs)
Is there any way to connect both my clusters even with self signed certificates ?
Elasticsearch's official documentation only mentions establishing trust using ca certification and not self signed ones.
For your information , I have security enabled in both of my clusters. Each cluster has 3 nodes. Please help!
whenever I am trying to create a connection from cluster B using
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster" : {
      "remote" : {
        "leader" : {
          "seeds" : [
            "IP-address:9300" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

it shows connection failed.

The both cluster don't need to have the same certificate. Can you share the full error?
Also, can you share the following API call result? GET /_remote/info
